# Graphics corruption in Ubuntu 16.04 on Kangaroo PC

Tags: 16.04, intel-graphics, intel

I tried to get Ubuntu 16.04 working on my Kangaroo PC (Intel Cherry Trail, x5-Z8500 chipset.)

Whenever I boot into the DE, I get a lot of graphical corruption that is present throughout every application or window I open. The corruption is also present during the lightdm login manager...It tends to follow the cursor but is rather random on what it affects.

I have attached an imgur album of screenshots of this happening. This has to be some software issue, as it works perfectly fine when running Windows 10.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

My `lspci` output is this (If it is of any help):

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 2280 (rev 20)  
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 22b0 (rev 20)  
00:0b.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 22dc (rev 20)  
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 22b5 (rev 20)   
00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Device 2298 (rev 20)  
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 22c8 (rev 20)   
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 229c (rev 20)   
01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 (rev 69)
```

My kernel version is 4.4.0-24-generic

Thank you.

Comment: Hi again. I did sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade to ensure that I had the most up to date software....This has actually improved on this mysterious issue. Now, the corruption is not present in any applications or windows, but still follows the cursor. The system is now usable, but is still getting graphical corruption around the cursor and anything it highlights. See screenshots of this: [link](http://imgur.com/a/VLukd)